# Is there a way to use picocli annotation processing for Kotlin projects using Maven build system?

Tags: maven, kotlin, piccolo

I see this [link](https://picocli.info/#_kotlin_projects_using_gradle) for annotation processing for Kotlin projects using Gradle, but nothing for Kotlin projects using Maven.

Comment: In the link there is a tab "Gradle" and one with "Maven" (Click on that with Maven)  https://picocli.info/#_using_build_tools  that will show a configuration..

Comment: I saw the link khmarbaise mentions, but that is for the java compiler which compiles java code.   I'm looking to add annotation processing of a kotlin project using the maven build system.